# facebook android SSO completes, but activity closes without calling onActivityResult()

Tags: android, facebook, single-sign-on

The problem I'm having is as the title suggests. I make the authorize() call but am never able to call authorizeCallback() because onActivityResult() is never called. SSO does complete, because it shows the permissions screen (with Don't Allow/Allow) and the app approval is shown on my Facebook settings page. Any ideas? I thought it might have something to do with the launchMode of the activity, but removed "singleInstance" and it didn't make a difference.

As I mentioned above, I can confirm the permissions activity is started in Facebook.java.

```
 try {
        Log.e("@@@", "Starting activity");
        activity.startActivityForResult(intent, activityCode);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        didSucceed = false;
    }
```

For what it's worth, I can confirm the code used below.

I've implemented the authorizeCallback() method in onActivityResult():

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    mStateHolder.getFacebook().authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

.. but it's never called. The authorize method I've used is as follows:

```
facebook.authorize(this, new String[]{ "user_birthday" }, new DialogListener() {
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onComplete()");
            // I make a request here..
        }
        // ...with the other methods as well
}
```

Other potentially useful info:

I'm running a Nexus One, 2.3.4

The Facebook app is installed

It works fine if I force the Dialog method, but I'm trying to get SSO working.

EDIT: Urgh! After much searching, I found the problem. There was a rogue Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY flag in the intent (which doesn't keep the activity in the stack). Thanks everyone for attempting to answer this.

EDIT2: removing launchMode=singleInstance does make a difference too btw.. I started getting the error "Failed to read calling package's signature".

Comment: What is the value of `activityCode`? A couple times I've accidentally used `0`, and per the documentation that will not result in a call to `onActivityResult()` even if the `Activity` is started with `startActivityForResult()`.

Answer (score 0):

How are you finishing your authentication activity? You have to set the Result type and maybe send a value back. e.g:

```
Intent data = new Intent();
data.putExtra(ApplicationConstants.EXTRA_IS_DONE, true);
setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
finish();
```